# HTML input type = file in Adobe AIR does not present file browser

Tags: html, file, upload, input, air

So the good old HTML file uploader tag  only presents a browse button (without associated text input) when rendered in a HTML based Adobe AIR application.  Upon clicking the browse button, nothing seems to happen.  I would expect a popup window so I can select a file.  I've seen examples of people using Javascript to call the AIR runtime to get a file and upload it, but I was wondering if anyone knew a complete HTML/Javascript way of doing this with AIR.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this does work.  I somehow managed to stop this from working, probably through a combination of cloning that part of the DOM elsewhere.